# The Lehmer-Comtet sequence

Tags: code-golf, sequence, integer, calculus

The Lehmer-Comtet sequence is a sequence such that **a(n)** is the **n**th derivative of **f(x) = x<sup>x</sup>** with respect to **x** as evaluated at **x = 1**.

## Task

Take a non-negative integer as input and output the **n**th term of the  Lehmer-Comtet sequence.

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf) so you should minimize the file size of your source code.

## Test Cases

[OEIS 5727](http://oeis.org/A005727)

Here are the first couple terms in order (copied from the OEIS)

```
1, 1, 2, 3, 8, 10, 54, -42, 944, -5112, 47160, -419760, 4297512, -47607144, 575023344, -7500202920, 105180931200, -1578296510400, 25238664189504, -428528786243904, 7700297625889920, -146004847062359040, 2913398154375730560, -61031188196889482880
```

Answer (score 13):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>77</s> 75 bytes, no differentiation builtins

```hs
x@(a:b)&y@(c:d)=a*c:zipWith(+)(b&y)(x&d)
s=1:s&(1:scanl(*)1[-1,-2..])
(s!!)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcQxDsIgFADQvaegC/m/ChHcSEh6A0eHpsMvFUukhEiH1sOLvuEtVF6PGGvdeyAzIT96cGZGS50zn5DvYVvghDDxA2HnMzbFKlM4/HOUInSoBqHOQks5YuMtlLbFulJIzLL8DmljsFJmng0XKfV1xPp1PtKzVHHTPw)

#### How it works

We represent a function as its infinite list of Taylor series coefficients about \$x = 1\$:

$$
f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{f^{(n)}(1)}{n!} (x - 1)^n
$$

is represented by \$[f(1), f'(1), f''(1), ...]\$.

The `&` operator multiplies two such functions using the product rule.  This lets us recursively define the function \$s(x) = x^x\$ in terms of itself using the differential equation

$$
s(1) = 1, \\
s'(x) = s(x) \cdot (1 + \ln x),
$$

where

$$
\ln x = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n - 1)!}{n!}(x - 1)^n.
$$

Answer (score 7):

## Mathematica, 19 bytes

```
D[x^x,{x,#-1}]/.x->1&
```

*-18 bytes from @Not a tree*

Comment: Unless I'm missing something, you can get this a lot shorter: `D[x^x,{x,#}]/.x->1&`, 19 bytes.

Comment: actually 21 bytes.. but yes! a lot shorter!

Comment: I don't think you need the `-1` — the sequence from OEIS starts at *n* = 0.

Comment: ok then! 19 bytes it is

Answer (score 5):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/) with Symbolic Package, <s>36</s> 32 bytes

```matlab
syms x
@(n)subs(diff(x^x,n),x,1)
```

The code defines an anonymous function which outputs a symbolic variable with the result.

[**Try it online!**](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/f@/uDK3WKGCy0EjT7O4NKlYIyUzLU2jIq5CJ09Tp0LHUPN/moKtQmJesbVCWn6RQh6QY2BlZKyjkJJZXKCRBtSlaa2QmpfyHwA)

Answer (score 5):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), 57 bytes

```hs
f 0=1
f n=f(n-1)-foldl(\a k->f(k-1)/(1-n/k)-a*k)0[1..n-1]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##DcoxDoMwDAXQvaf4Q4ekkkN8gPQilMESWCAnJmp7/8D69Hb52VbrGIpc@KHwosGJI@lZ1xo@AqO3BrtpCkw@WSR5Wcwzp3THZTQ5HAX9e/gfTzTpUMw5Jc7LuAA)

No built-ins for differentiating or algebra. Outputs floats.

Answer (score 4):

## Python with [SymPy](http://www.sympy.org/en/index.html), <s>77</s> <s>75</s> <s>58</s> 57 bytes

*1 byte saved thanks to @notjagan*

*17 bytes saved thanks to @AndersKaseorg*

```python
from sympy import*
lambda n:diff('x^x','x',n).subs('x',1)
```

Comment: `lambda n:diff('x**x','x',10).subs('x',1)` doesn’t require `sympy.abc`.

Comment: Ummm ... where do you use `n`?

Comment: @ZacharyT thanks! coincidentally I tested anders' proposal right with n=10, so it gave the same result :) fixed now

Comment: -1 byte by replacing `x**x` with `x^x`.

Answer (score 3):

## [SageMath](http://www.sagemath.org/), <s>33</s> 32 bytes

```sage
lambda n:diff(x^x,x,n).subs(x=1)
```

[Try it on SageMathCell](https://sagecell.sagemath.org/?z=eJxLs81JzE1KSVTIs0rJTEvTqIir0KnQydPUKy5NKtaosDXU5OWKTtPI01RIyy9SyFPIzFMoSsxLT9UwMtGMBQBrsRMp&lang=sage)

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 150 bytes

```python
lambda n:0**n or sum(L(n-1,r)for r in range(n))
L=lambda n,r:0<=r<=n and(0**n or n*L(n-2,r-1)+L(~-n,r-1)+(r-~-n)*L(~-n,r)if r else n<2or-~-n*L(n-1,0))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY0xDoJAEEV7TzHlzMomgIkFYW/AEWzWwOom8DEDFjZeHReR2P0/P2/e4zXfR5yW4C5L74dr6wlVbgxoVJqeAzcMW2QqIXWlCFKPW8cQOTRuJzKt8tpp7UAeLe88zEqXmdpCjg2/LbbIalMW8ztJDOl1108doS7H72g2by6yrOb4NxdnqR4aMXPgmOYP)

Exponential runtime complexity. Uses the formula given in the OEIS page.

Comment: `n>=r>=0` saves a byte.

Comment: You can also save a byte by putting `0**n` after `sum(...)`.

Comment: [You can rearrange your addition to save a third byte.](https://tio.run/##RY1BCoMwFET3PUWW/6sBtdCFNJ7AI3STomkDOpGvLrrp1W0UpbvhDW9m/MzvgOvqzGPt7fBsrUI1LQM1BF1kwi6IEuWhxOLVEZgjyJMEl8acQiYVaiO1yS1a2koVhER/NTg5h1LsscxEF5weNEbv4n7XT53CvQy7dDg587rd@/99ceNqFI@ZHPlY/wA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: [Save two bytes by using bitwise or](https://tio.run/##RY1NCoMwEIX3PUWWM2rAWOhCGk/gEbpJ0bQBfZHRLgqlV7cqSncf73d4T8@I8@ztbe5cf2@cQjm@eqoJ2mTCPooSFaDE4dESmD95kuBU2yOeSYnKSmVzh4ZWU0Uh0V8NTo6ZFBsWmWjD6a4uGPyy3nZjq3At4lbaOznzvJ6H/7m5cDlIwESewmL/AA "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: [Save two more bytes by using `n<1` instead of `0**n`](https://tio.run/##RY1NCoMwEIX3PUWWM2rAWOhCjCfwCN2kaNqAvshoF4XSq1srSneP9/eNr/kRcV68vS69G26tUyin50ANQZtM2EdRogKUONw7AvMbSZKfGnvUMylRW6lt7tASKhOFRH80ODlOUmyyyEQbTnd3lcGv310/dQpVEbfRvsmZlx86/NHmwuUoATN5Cmv8BQ "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Comment: You can save a byte by changing `0<=r<=n and` to `n>=r>=0and`, as @Olmman said.

Answer (score 1):

## Python3+mpmath 52 bytes

```
from mpmath import*
lambda n:diff(lambda x:x**x,1,n)
```

-3 bytes, Thanks @Zachary T

Comment: You should change the language to python3+mpmath, since mpmath is not a standard library.

Comment: You can change your first line to `from mpmath import*`, and the second to `diff(lambda x:x**x,1,n)`. (just removing unnecessary spaces)

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), <s>288</s> 261 bytes

Differentiation without differentiation built-in.

```python
p=lambda a,n:lambda v:v and p(a*n,n-1)or a
l=lambda v:v and p(1,-1)
e=lambda v:v and m(e,a(p(1,0),l))or 1
a=lambda f,g:lambda v:v and a(f(1),g(1))or f(0)+g(0)
m=lambda f,g:lambda v:v and a(m(f(1),g),m(g(1),f))or f(0)*g(0)
L=lambda n,f=e:n and L(n-1,f(1))or f(0)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##fY9BCoMwEEX3niLLGTsFQ1cNeAMvMcUkDZhRRISePk1ES7HQzfDh/cdnptfyHOWW0tQOHB89KyYxe1zNqlh6NQHXQnLVOM6Kq6H94ZoyrOwZRLDEUHCDNGDRdcVHy5E/LzE40Eg@n1J20ODF51PFv1LcNaQIxSX30etN7w5dyLXWyOZ1kF8i97WVXA5BBVEzi7dwRzPNQRboICCmNw)

### How it works

Each of the first five lines define functions and their derivatives and their results when evaluated at `1`. Their derivatives are also functions.

- `p` is power i.e. `a*x^n`
- `l` is logarithm i.e. `ln(x)`
- `e` is exponential i.e. `exp(x)`
- `a` is addition i.e. `f(x)+g(x)`
- `m` is multiplication i.e. `f(x)*g(x)`

Usage: for example, `exp(ln(x)+3x^2)` would be represented as `e(l()+p(3,2))`. Let `x=e(l()+p(3,2))`. To find its derivative, call `x(1)`. To find its result when evaluated at `1`, call `x(0)`.

Bonus: [symbolic differentiation](https://tio.run/##pZLRaoMwFIbvfQoRhHNsVia7E3yVSaiJC8QsmLRkT29jk6wrUzvYhRiOH/m//6D@sh@f6m2eT5Iak@smy3vG864TStiuA8MkJ5QobJbTkZLbS7V@FMj@hmAzMXueVK4hcFXgIv5SY6Avj3RgU6SxU0xMQFEK916KooSHdMyCrWw2HGqylfi6EyYVOCzi3Wx1Ezzugbd8NXoEFlQ5Bld@7AHXVeodFeY0lAaL0n9LF0Yxui5GhqQWgofWj1YdKdzNIrstGdEL4CGi/rgjvlgfgjr8cCff5wFTkfH/RcbfVZDE4XAf8qflqj@Xq56Um13LvNfyD9ZIpN8rZnoSyoJbhNKD8xU)

Comment: You can save a lot of bytes by using `exec` compression. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##RY7RCsIwDEV/pRRWEo3i8MmO/sF@Imo7B2ssQ0S/fqYi8yUP557LTXk/bnc5Lkt8xQvYEhyT@KYAb4Rk1@J9NtxNwVXWkoIuBpd8kyFCQkrQYnXajhXT4BuGymj4BQkOuB30dHkV8k9BylA9Squ6@ap9cEIpRDXrqhoTIKIXw3I1Pehj63Jt2f0cy8SXCLaxZN3TP7@mxX/gNJg4n6@sGJek1dGMYmaWIcIJfZlHeUAPo6Yf "Python 3 – Try It Online")

Answer (score 0):

## [Pari/GP](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), 32 bytes

```
n->n!*Vec((y=1+x+O(x^n++))^y)[n]
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gsytRNL/ifpmD7P0/XLk9RKyw1WUOj0tZQu0LbX6MiLk9bW1MzrlIzOi/2f1p@kUaegq2CoY6CoYGBjkJBUWZeCVBESUHXDkikaeRpamr@BwA)